# How to parse lines from a Buffer with streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

So, I get a file stream from STDIN with line breaks, but the stream delivers buffers where the line breaks disappear.

How would I process/parse lines with the Stream approach?

```
util.inherits(Parser, Transform);

Parser.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  this.push(this._parseRow(data));
  done();
};

// Parse a data row into an object
Parser.prototype._parseRow = function(row) {
  var result = row.toString().split("\r");
  var fields = result.toString().split(";");
  var bank = { a: fields[0], b: fields[1].trim() };
  return bank.toString();
};
```

But the output has line breaks randomly.

Comment: try using line feed `\n` instead of carriage return `\r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://npmjs.org/package/split) module.

```
var split = require('split');
process.stdin.pipe(split()).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Note that split will actually remove the newlines, so you'll have to re-add them if you want to keep newlines.

Comment: thanks, that answer actually helps to improve my stream understanding a lot!